# call of overloaded *** <unresolved overloaded function type>)' is ambiguous

Tags: c++, function, overloading

Please help me how to resolve this error

```
template <typename Inputlterator, typename Outputlterator, typename Predicate>
Outputlterator copy_if( Inputlterator begin, Inputlterator end, Outputlterator destBegin, Predicate p) 
{
    return remove_copy_if(begin, end,destBegin, not1( ptr_fun( p ) ) );
}
template <class T> bool is_not_3( T val ) {
    return val != 3;
}
void foo( ) {
    vector<int> v;
    v.push_back( 1 );
    v.push_back( 2 );
    v.push_back( 3 );
    copy_if( v.begin( ), v.end( ), ostream_iterator<int>( cout, " " ), is_not_3<int> );
}
```

And I get an error saying that
: error: call of overloaded 'copy_if(std::vector::iterator, std::vector::iterator, std::ostream_iterator, )' is ambiguous

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite this statement

```
copy_if( v.begin( ), v.end( ), ostream_iterator<int>( cout, " " ), //...);
```

like

```
::copy_if( v.begin( ), v.end( ), ostream_iterator<int>( cout, " " ), //...);
^^^
```

Otherwise your function conflicts with the standard algorithm `std::copy_if`

The problem arised due to using by you the derictive

```
using namespace std;
```

Pay attention to that the function call in your code snippet is not syntaxically finished. You forgot to specify the last argument.

Comment: Thanks for reply Vlad. Sorry there were lot of spaces for last argument so it was not visible. I edited the post. Adding Scope resolution helped to resolve the error. Thanks a lot